# How do I make flycheck find required file in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, flycheck

I have 2 files in the same directory, say `a.el` and `a-test.el`.

**a.el**

```
;; some functions
(provide 'a)
```

**a-test.el**

```
(require 'a)
```

flycheck put a warning on the `require` in `a-test.el` says

> Cannot open load files: a

How do I make flycheck find the required file in the same directory ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flycheck does not use `load-path` when checking Emacs Lisp files.  Instead, it uses `flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path`, which is empty by default.

To make Flycheck use the current `load-path`, add the following to your `init.el`:

```
(setq-default flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path 'inherit)
```

However, I recommend to use [Cask](https://github.com/cask/cask) in your projects, and then install [flycheck-cask](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck-cask), to automatically use the right load path and package directory in Emacs Lisp projects.

Comment: My current flycheck setup [init.el#L58-L65](https://github.com/RangiLin/emacs.d/blob/master/init.el#L58-L65), but still have no luck :(

Comment: Obviously you need a Cask file in your project, and you need to use packages.  If it's just for init.el, Cask might be overkill.  Just set the aforementioned variable then.